# Let $G$ be a cyclic group $G=\langle a\mid a^6\rangle $ and let $H=\langle a^2\rangle $. Is that true then there is one relation in $H$, $(a^2)^3=1$?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a cyclic group $G=\langle a\mid a^6\rangle $ and let $H=\langle a^2\rangle $.

My question is: Is that true then there is one relation in $H$, $(a^2)^3=1$?

Thank you

Comment: That would be correct, yes.

Comment: No. $(a^2)^6=1$ and $(a^2)^2 = (a^2)^{-1}$ are also relations.

Comment: sorry, I forget to notice that relation is not equal $(a^2)^6=1$.

Comment: Of course there are infinitely many relations. I thought perhaps you meant to ask whether all relations are consequences of $(a^2)^3=1$, and the answer to that is yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

All relations of the normal subgroup $\langle a^2\rangle$ of $\langle a\mid a^6\rangle$ generated by $a^2$ are consequences of $(a^2)^3=1.$ By Tietze transformations, $(a^2)^3=1$ would suffice for $\langle a^2\rangle$.